# Compile multiple applications with multiple source files using makefile

Tags: compilation, makefile, gnu-make

I want to compile multiple applications with multiple source files using a single makefile.
All sources are in a single directory.

apps/src/
 app1_file1.cpp
 app1_file2.cpp
 app1_main.cpp
 app2_file1.cpp
 app2_file2.cpp
 app2_main.cpp

apps/Makefile

### Makefile

```
APPS:= app1_main app2_main  
app1_main_SOURCES:= app1_file1.cpp app1_file2.cpp app1_main.cpp
app2_main_SOURCES:= app2_file1.cpp app2_file2.cpp app2_main.cpp

default: app1_main app2_main

%: $(foreach $CPP_FILE,$(%_SOURCES),$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(CPP_FILE)))
     gcc ....
%.o: src/%.cpp
     gcc ...
```

### Question

I want $(%_SOURCES) to be replaced with 'app1_main_SOURCES, app2_main_SOURCES'.
But this doesn't seem to happen with the above code.
Can someone suggest the right way to use % to have it replaced with the variable names i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

foreach happens when make parses the makefile. It is long done by the time your rules are running.

Also, you don't want the `$` in the first argument to foreach (i.e. you want `$(foreach CPP_FILE,...,... $(CPP_FILE) ...)`).

I would probably do something like (untested):

```
$(foreach APP,$(APPS),$(APP): $(addprefix src/,$($(APP)_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))

%:
        gcc ...
%.o: src/%.cpp
        gcc ...
```

That is, use the for loop to set up the prerequisite relationships between the applications and their object files and then just let the % rule handle the target -> rule mapping.

Comment: To generate the executable (using the % target), i need to refer to all the .o files of the app. How do i do that?

Comment: Use the automatic variable for target prerequisites. See [the make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. First let's get it working.

It's just as easy to write a list of *objects* as a list of *sources*, and saves us work later:

```
app1_main_OBJECTS:= app1_file1.o app1_file2.o app1_main.o
app2_main_OBJECTS:= app2_file1.o app2_file2.o app2_main.o

default: app1_main app2_main

app1_main: $(app1_main_OBJECTS)
app2_main: $(app2_main_OBJECTS)

app%_main:
    gcc $^ -o $@
```

That list of app rules is redundant and tedious if there are many apps. We can reduce it:

```
define rule_template
$(1): $$($(1)_OBJECTS)
endef

$(foreach app,app1_main app2_main,$(eval $(call rule_template,$(app))))
```

Or if your version of Make supports `SECONDEXPANSION`, it's even simpler:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:                
app1_main app2_main: $$($$@_OBJECTS)
```

And you can simplify things even further by defining a list of apps:

```
APPS := app1_main app2_main
```

...but this answer is getting long.